# ASP.NET membership data storage issue

Tags: asp.net

I have created a sample web application in Visual Studio 2010. It stores Membership data(users, roles etc) in a .mdf file in App_data folder. But I don't wanna do this. I wanna store data in SQL server database.

For that I Google a lot but could not find solution. Here is what I am doing so for. First I create application then by using Web configuration tool I set users, roles etc and when hit provider tab it throws following error:

**`Could not establish a connection to the database. If you have not yet created the SQL Server database, exit the Web Site Administration tool, use the aspnet_regsql command-line utility to create and configure the database, and then return to this tool to set the provider.`**

Then I execute `aspnet_regsql` utility and created a database in SQL Server and again open web configuration tool but error is same, no change.

Please guide either i am going in right direction or not. If right then how can I store data in `aspnet_regsql` generated  SQL server database?

Note that I am using .NET framework 4, SQL server 2008 R2, Visual studio 2010. In fact I was expecting that there will be connection string in `web.config` file just like other data driven controls do. But no entries go in `web.config` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well normally the asp.net membership is used for sqlserver for big applications. first go to the web.config and comment the connection string already there and add a connection string that connects to the sqlserver and the cataloge name.

```
<add name="ApplicationServices"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**replace it with**

```
<add name="ApplicationServices"  connectionString="data source=servername;database name=databasename;user name= username; password=pass;
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

then configure normally in the aspnet_regsql. and this will do the drill for sure.

Comment: Nayyad in my application there is no connection string already exist in .config file.

Comment: add one in the a configuration tag and in side it open a connection string tag and inside it put the above code.